# How do I install rake

Tags: ruby

```
sudo yum install ruby
```

I did this on my Amazon EC2 AMI, but I still don't find the 'rake' command. Isn't it part of this installation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rake is a Ruby gem, it doesn't come with Ruby. [Install RubyGems](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/3) and then install Rake using `[sudo] gem install rake`.

Comment: The provided link is dead.